# jupyter lab上でOctaveで出力画像をsvgではなくpngにする方法はありますか？

Tags: jupyter-notebook, svg, octave

jupyter lab上でOctaveでグラフを描画すると自分の環境ではsvg画像が出力されてしまうのですが、これをpngやjpg等が出力されるようにする方法はありますか？
サンプル数が10^6のオーダーなのでベクター画像であるsvgで描画してしまうと非常に重くて困ってます。

使用言語はOctaveで、カーネルもIOctaveです
OSはMacOSです
ライブラリはデフォルトから追加してません

出力部分は
`plot(data)`
です

備考
- iPythonではpngで出力されました。octave固有の問題なのでしょうか。ご指摘ありがとうございます

Comment: 念の為の確認なのですが、IOctave というのは [octave_kernel](https://pypi.org/project/octave_kernel/) のことでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

octave_kernel の[サンプル notebook](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/blob/master/octave_kernel.ipynb) によると、`%plot --format png` のようにして出力形式を指定できるようです。以下は小さい動作例です。

```
%plot --format png
plot([])
```

私の環境ではこれで svg / png / jpeg を切り替えることができました (Windows 10 + Jupyter 4.4.0 + octave_kernel 0.28.4 + Octave 4.4.1)。